# How can I disable typing in a ttk.Combobox tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Combobox that I can currently type into. I want it to be so that the user can only choose a valid option from the drop down.

I can't seem to find a similar question online, and I don't see anything in the documentation that could help me out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can set the `state` to `"readonly"`

```
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly", 
                  values=("one", "two", "three"))
```

From the [python 3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.ttk.html#options):

> **state**: One of “normal”, “readonly”, or “disabled”. In the “readonly” state, the value may not be edited directly, and the user can only selection of the values from the dropdown list. In the “normal” state, the text field is directly editable. In the “disabled” state, no interaction is possible.